# Access element in partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm populating a table that is inside a partial view. The partial is rendered and the content is passed to the wrapper div via ajax.

```
$("#Add").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mostrarModalLoading();
    $.post("/Pesca/panel/AgregarSolicitud", $('#pdForm').serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#partial_table").html(data);
    }).done(function (e) {
        ocultarModalLoading();
    });
});
```

When the table is created, the last column of every row has a button, and when is clicked the view model of the page should be sent to an action to delete the parent row of the button. 
[image]

I'm trying to get the button in a .js file and post the model but I can't access it because the partial is rendered after the page is loaded, and it's updated everytime I add a new row to the table.

```
$("#partial_table > table").find("tbody").on("click", ".eliminar", function (e) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mostrarModalLoading();
            $.post("/Pesca/panel/EliminarSolicitud", $('#pdForm').serialize() + "&idPago=" + id, function (data) {
                $("#partial_table").html(data);
            }).done(function (e) {
                ocultarModalLoading();
            });
        });
```

Is there a way to access the elements of the partial view? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to delete the associated `<tr>` element when you click the button?

Comment: And why do you have all those hidden inputs? (all you should be posting is the ID of the record to you delete method)

Comment: Yes, but that's subsequent. I need to post the view model to an action with that button because I need to delete an item of the list on which the table is based.

Comment: Yes, but all you should be posting is the ID of the record, not the whole model (and none of you hidden inputs are required0

Comment: I use hiddens because if i use just the displays, the values aren't sent to the action.

Comment: I mean, when I add a new row to the table I need to send the whole model.

Comment: Again, you only post the ID! What is the ID property of your model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173433/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-andre-villanueva).